# Sub-select from comma separated list in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, csv

I have tables like so:

TableA

```
id    id_link_list
1     1,2
```

TableB

```
id    info
1     blah
2     blah-more
```

I'm struggling to include the `TableA.id_link_list` column (which is already a comma separated list) into a `SELECT IN ()` query

This works fine:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(b.info separator "; ") as infolist 
FROM `TableB` as b 
where b.id in ('1,2')
```

But this doesn't.

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(b.info separator "; ") as infolist 
FROM `TableB` as b 
where b.id in (
    select id_link_list 
    from `TableA` 
    where id=1
)
```

What can I do to work around it?

Comment: fwiw - I dummied [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce4c7927b67cd63343ae87378bc8a2a5) up for you when I got this in the review queue before I noticed you'd self-answered. Consider reading this page for guidance on making your questions more answerable for others: [mcve]

Comment: Storing comma separated values in a single column is a really bad idea. You just found one reason why. If you have the chance, fix your data model and refactor that to a proper one-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just realized I could put the link column in TableB to solve the problem

TableA

```
id    
1
```

TableB

```
id    info         tablea_id
1     blah         1
2     blah-more    1
```

Like so

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(b.info separator "; ") as infolist 
FROM `TableB` as b 
where b.tablea_id=1
```

Comment: *I just realized I could put the link column in TableB* You're cheater.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b.info separator "; ") infolist 
FROM `TableA` a, `TableB` b 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.id_link_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where b.id in ('1,2')
```

does not work (unless `id` is the 3-character string "1,2").  You want

```
where b.id in (1,2)  -- efficient
```

or

```
where FIND_IN_SET(b.id, '1,2')  -- inefficient
```